HTML unescape does not work with BeautifulSoup replace_with
I am trying to edit the inner HTML of some elements in Python using BeautifulSoup. Here is a simple example:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html

html_str = '<div><span><strong>Hello world</strong></span></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str, 'html.parser')
span = soup.select_one('span')
span.replace_with('message: ' + html.unescape(span.decode_contents()) + ', end of message')

print(soup)

I was expecting to get a decoded string, like:
<div>message: <strong>Hello world</strong>, end of message</div>
But instead I got:
<div>message: &lt;strong&gt;Hello world&lt;/strong&gt;, end of message</div>
Notice that this behaviour only happens when the target element contains a child, e.g. if you try to execute this code on the strong element (with soup.select_one('strong')), it works as expected.

What is decode_contents()? I can't find it in the BS4 documentation.

replace_with() doesn't parse the argument as HTML, it treats it as literal text. So tags are converted to entities so they'll be literal.

You should parse the replacement into tags with BeautifulSoup(), then you can pass that as the argument to replace_with().

Or use soup.new_tag(). See the example at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with

The easiest way is to use .replace_with with new BeautifulSoup object, e.g.:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_str = "<div><span><strong>Hello world</strong></span></div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str, "html.parser")

span = soup.select_one("span")
span.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(f"message: {str(span)}, end of message", "html.parser"))

print(soup)

Prints:
<div>message: <span><strong>Hello world</strong></span>, end of message</div>

